# JavaScript - Missing Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8, ecmascript-2016

I discovered this weird thing by an accident. I was writting some issue on GitHub and, as you know, to use some language highlighting in GitHub post you should encapsulate it in tripple [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent). For example, if you want to use JavaScript, you should do this:

````
```JavaScript
// Your code
```
````

It will use JavaScript highlighting in your code snippet.

However, while I was writtin a post there, I accidentally copied whole code snipped from edit mode (including grave accents) and pasted it in `js` file. I've forgotten to remove accents, though. This is my code in `js` file:

````
function test(){
  ```JavaScript
  console.log(1);
  ```
}
````

It should be syntax error, of course. But, what surprises me is that Node.js compiled it without any errors. I couldn't believe. No cyntax error at all. How is this even possible?

So, I suppose tripple grave accent has special meaning in JavaScript (maybe multiline string like in Python?). I searchen on internet, but I found nothing. Why is EcmaScript allowing this? What is an example use of it?

Comment: @JaromandaX. *"repl: Unexpected token (1:8)"* - this is what I've got on your link.

Comment: @JaromandaX. Maybe next time you should escape special chars first, not just copy-paste link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

````
  ```JavaScript
  console.log(1);
  ```
````

is interpreted as per the [`12.3.7.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tagged-templates-runtime-semantics-evaluation) as the expression followed by a template literal.

So, the first empty template literal is evaluated to an empty string, then it is applied as a tag to the second template literal.

> `MemberExpression : MemberExpression TemplateLiteral`
>
> 1. Let `tagRef` be the result of evaluating `MemberExpression`.
> 2. Let `thisCall` be this `MemberExpression`.
> 3. Let `tailCall` be `IsInTailPosition(thisCall)`.
> 4. Return `EvaluateCall(tagRef, TemplateLiteral, tailCall)`.

So it throws since a string is not a function.

This syntax is allowed so that it was possible to obtain tags as a result of an arbitrary expression evaluation, eg:

```
foo.bar`str`
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out using Babel. However, I'm still wondering why is that even allowed? Is there any use of it?

Comment: @hesoyam_ you can retrieve a reference to a tag as an expression. eg: "foo.bar\`str\`". So it is allowed for such cases.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I asked is there any use of tripple literals like in my post?

Comment: @hesoyam_ it's not triple literals, it's an expression (that is comprised of an empty template literal) followed by a template literal. Practically - it cannot be evaluated, since an empty string is not a function.

Comment: No, I asked somethign different. I asked is there a use of what I posted? Is there any use of tagging template literals to template literal?

Comment: It would always fail. So if you want something to be always failed when you evaluate it - then it's your use case. So, I don't think there is a *practical* use of such expression.

Comment: @hesoyam_ I am the one who upvoted actually. https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhkpgbopqykdkrh/Screenshot%202017-04-20%2013.48.24.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Backticks are part of Javascript's grammar as of ES2015 and are used for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Your code does not contain any lexical syntax errors, the template version will throw an error when you run the function because of [template tagging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals_and_escape_sequences) syntax attempting to evaluate the second and third templates. So to reiterate: no syntax errors exist, however, when you consider template tagging, the way this actually ends up getting evaluated is

```
""("Javascript\n console.log(1);\n")("")
```

Which will not work because `""` is not a function. It is expecting characters before the backticks to be a tagging function. If you replaced the first set of backticks with a function, it would work:

````js
function format(msg) {
   return function(secondMsg) {
     return "!!" + msg + secondMsg + "!!";
   };
}


console.log(format`Javascript\n console.log(1);\n```)
````

Comment: @zerkms was wondering the same... maybe they were thinking it compiled to `Javascript\`console.log(1);\``

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is **NOT EQUIVALENT** to what I posted, because it doesn't trow error on calling `test`.

Comment: Again, this is not equivalent to what I've written because calling with template literal and calling with string behaves differently. However, I understood what you're talking about.